# Regular expressions - pick up consecutive words that start with a capital letter

Tags: php, regex

I have to pick up consecutive capital-letter starting words in a text (using PHP `preg_match()`).

So in this text - "this is Some text" it should pick up word "Some", but in this text - "this is Another Piece Of text" it should pick up "Another Piece Of".

I currently have this expression - `([A-Z][a-z]+)+`, but it only picks up every single capital case word. I need them in as a whole line (e.g - `[0] => "Another Piece Of"`, but I currently get `[0] => "Another", [1] => "Piece", [2] => "Of"`)

How should I update it so that it does what I need?

Comment: Does not look like a task for regular expressions.

Comment: what is expected result once you fiind them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if (preg_match('~[A-Z][a-z]*(?> [A-Z][a-z]*)*~', $text, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
```

`(?> [A-Z][a-z]*)*` represents optional other words.

To be more flexible you can change it to `(?>\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*`

Note: if you need to deal with accented words, you can use the `\p{Ll}` and `\p{Lu}` character classes:

```
if (preg_match('~\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?>\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)*~', $text, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
```